# Correct use of Laravel program logic for an API call?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm writing a translator API that will call various other APIs to perform a translation depending on the service requested. I would think I should put this into a controller, but what if I need to access the translator class from within another controller or within a view?

Should I put part of it into a model?

For the sake of speed, I don't want to have to call the service like I would an external URL using `Request::create()` if it is an internal request.

Something like this works in a view, but I feel like there should be a more elegant way of doing this.

```
{{ App::make('TranslatorController')->show($text, $to, App::getLocale()); }}
```

Comment: I would suggest, Write separate classes/interfaces, service providers and facades. Implement the interface for each translation service/API. And bind the interface to the service dynamically based on request Or You could even write a Laravel Package which would of course be useful for multiple projects and let you access anywhere.

Comment: Sounds legit. Please make this an answer so I can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requested, Here's the answer!

I would suggest, Write separate classes/interfaces, service providers and facades. Implement the interface for each translation service/API. And bind the interface to the service dynamically based on request Or You could even write a Laravel Package which would of course be useful for multiple projects and let you access anywhere.

Hope this helps!